# How to build a Joomla extension ?

Tags: joomla, module

firstly i want to know f there is any difference between **Extension** and **Plugin** and **Module**

Then i want to Know how To Start with This ? what tools and Knowledge i must have

and What is The best Martial For This ?

Comment: Not really a programming question

Comment: had he said how to PROGRAM an extension would you have been happier? It is obviously a programming question by the subject, and someone with bad english by the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Components, Modules and Plugins are all types of Extensions, just like Audi, BMW and Ford are all types of cars.

**Components** are your main applications such as forum, shop system and so on. These are usually displayed in the center of your site (where you articles are displayed).

**Modules** are like small widgets that you would normally see on the side of your website, such as a shoutbox, Twitter Feed etc.

**Plugins** basically manipulate the site behaviour by firing events, for example it could be used to load a library or integrate the user profiles between 2 components.

To start learning, you should first of all understand how Joomla works, paying special attention to the fact it's MVC based. Have a looks through the [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org).

Once you start to feel confident, trying making a Hello World module, install it and have a mess around. To get you started, either read the [Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Module_for_Joomla_2.5), view [this video](http://www.slideshare.net/vishwashgaur/simple-module-development-in-joomla-25), or use a [Module Generator](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras/module-generator.html).

Or should you want to develop a component, start off by following the documentation on [Developing a Basic Component for Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

Plugins provide rather a lot of possibilities, therefore it would be best to start [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Development) and choose which way you want to go on from there.

Just a word of advice, don't start to use Joomla 1.5, either go for 2.5 or 3.0 ;)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_(general_definitions)

Extensions are something generic covering Components, Plugins and Modules. Plugins and modules are both separate things. See the link above for a more detailed explanation of this.

Assuming you know about HTML, CSS, PHP and Javascript (Mootools for Joomla 2.5 and jQuery for Joomla 3.0) - then I'd start by reading through the developers articles on the Joomla Docs page here: http://docs.joomla.org/Developers

Module Development: http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Development

Plugin Development: http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Development